# Excluding search expression from result?

Tags: regex

Very soring about posting this question, but even if i am a noob in RegEx, i'v started to learn them by myself, but i didn't get the answer for this case.

I am using group, and i wanted to exclude from my result the search caractere i 've used. This is an exemple :

My String : Hand #97407583861: dhihidhi Hand #97407583862: djodjidji Hand #97407583863: 
The Regex i use : (?Hand.#\d*:)

The results, i wanted to have in my groups :
97407583861
97407583862
97407583863
97407583864

Best regards

Comment: Sorry of asking that, but for everybody it seems to be very easy but i don't know what is the correct term. (excluding-group, non including group)??? I am a little bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should help:

```
string pattern = @"Hand\s#(?<Num>\d+):";
RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
string targetString = @"Hand #97407583861: dhihidhi Hand #97407583862: djodjidji Hand #97407583863:";
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(targetString))
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var number = match.Groups["Num"].Value;
    }
}
```

Tested using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester).

Comment: Hey... what a quick answer ! And it is also a good answer ;) My mistake was not so wrong, i just misplace the grouping name ;) I'v tested it on my .Net program and it did the trick. But i do you know i was on .Net ;) TY anyways